# Not able to iterate object array id inside of handlebars url method - node.js

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, express-handlebars, x-http-method-override

Experimenting with REST http methods in node.js using method-override package, express and express-handlebars. Oddly, I am able to loop through an array of objects using handlebars, but when I try to assign the specific id to the url method it will only assign the 1st item in that loop.

on html page will show
foo 1
bar 2
foobar 3

when button click regardless of the button picked it will read after the button is clicked as: Your ID is: 1

Can someone point out why my button method urls are not getting assigned the specific id even though my page can read them?

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');

const methodOverride = require('method-override');


const app = express();
app.use(methodOverride('_method'));

var PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const products = [
    {id: 5, name: 'foo'},
    {id: 2, name: 'bar'},
    {id: 3, name: 'foobar'}
];

app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({
   defaultLayout: 'main'
}));

app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    res.render("index", { products });
});

app.delete('/:id?', (req, res, next) => {
    res.send('your id is: ' + req.params.id);
});

app.listen(PORT, ()=> console.log('This s*** is bananas'));
```

index.handlebars

```
<ul>
    {{#each products}}
        <li>{{this.name}}</li>
        <form method="POST" action="/{{this.id}}?_method=DELETE">
        <button type="submit">DELETE</button>
        <form>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your HTML is invalid. Your are missing the "/" in your closing form tag, `</form>`. Your browser, in trying to make sense of the invalid markup, is rendering only the first form, with `action=/1`. All of the buttons submit this form.